# SSD has a lot of bad sectors on Windows, but I can't find any bad sectors in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, ssd, bad-sectors

The title is self-explained, on Windows PE, I used DiskGenius to fix the drive, the EFI partition is screwed so I decided to remake one.

After I got in PE, I opened DiskGenius, and realize it took so long to load, I saw the bad sectors message after it loads.

The message shows it has many bad sectors at around 2,000 to 2,500, then I tried to read it in hex editor, once I got to that part, it took like 10min to load, and a bunch of bad sector messages.

Also, whatever when I tries to verify the disk or use other tools to analyse the disk, it stuck forever(and if I tries to close it it took an hour to close).

So, I decided to fix them in Linux, then I booted into Ubuntu. While it boots, it show something about disk auth failed and limiting the speed of the disk(the bad sector one), after that, I ran `badblocks -v /dev/sdb` to find bad sectors, but surprise it didn't find any bad sector.

Then, I used gparted to remake the partition table, and got into pe again. I scanned again and problem remains. (Yes, there's still no bad sectors on Linux).

```
Drives: INTEL SSDSC2BW240A4(240gb, the screwed up one), TOSHIBA DT01ACA100(1tb, linux drive)
BIOS controller mode: ACPI, Hot plug enabled
```

```
Here is the SMART status information.

    === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
    Model Family:     Intel 53x and Pro 1500/2500 Series SSDs
    Device Model:     INTEL SSDSC2BW240A4
    Serial Number:    PHDA436001J52403GN
    LU WWN Device Id: 5 5cd2e4 04ba3de42
    Firmware Version: DC32
    User Capacity:    240,057,409,536 bytes [240 GB]
    Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
    Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
    TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
    Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
    ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
    SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
    Local Time is:    Sat Dec  3 21:35:57 2022 CST
    SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
    SMART support is: Enabled
    AAM feature is:   Unavailable
    APM level is:     254 (maximum performance)
    Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
    Write cache is:   Enabled
    DSN feature is:   Unavailable
    ATA Security is:  Disabled, NOT FROZEN [SEC1]
    Wt Cache Reorder: Unavailable
    
    === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
    SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
    
    General SMART Values:
    Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                        was completed without error.
                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
    Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                        been run.
    Total time to complete Offline 
    data collection:        ( 5860) seconds.
    Offline data collection
    capabilities:            (0x7f) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                        Abort Offline collection upon new
                        command.
                        Offline surface scan supported.
                        Self-test supported.
                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                        Selective Self-test supported.
    SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                        power-saving mode.
                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
    Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                        General Purpose Logging supported.
    Short self-test routine 
    recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
    Extended self-test routine
    recommended polling time:    (  48) minutes.
    Conveyance self-test routine
    recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
    SCT capabilities:          (0x0025) SCT Status supported.
                        SCT Data Table supported.
    
    SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
    Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
    ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
      5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
      9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec -O--CK   100   100   000    -    6308h+03m+03.040s
     12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   096   096   000    -    4193
    170 Available_Reservd_Space PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
    171 Program_Fail_Count      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
    172 Erase_Fail_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
    174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    172
    183 SATA_Downshift_Count    -O--CK   100   100   000    -    50
    184 End-to-End_Error        PO--CK   100   100   090    -    0
    187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
    190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O--CK   030   051   000    -    30 (Min/Max 16/51)
    192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    172
    199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   100   100   000    -    774
    225 Host_Writes_32MiB       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1156140
    226 Workld_Media_Wear_Indic -O--CK   100   100   000    -    65535
    227 Workld_Host_Reads_Perc  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    49
    228 Workload_Minutes        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    65535
    232 Available_Reservd_Space PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
    233 Media_Wearout_Indicator -O--CK   083   083   000    -    0
    241 Host_Writes_32MiB       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1156140
    242 Host_Reads_32MiB        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1133327
    249 NAND_Writes_1GiB        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    133125
                                ||||||_ K auto-keep
                                |||||__ C event count
                                ||||___ R error rate
                                |||____ S speed/performance
                                ||_____ O updated online
                                |______ P prefailure warning
    
    General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
    SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
    Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
    0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
    0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Device Statistics log
    0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
    0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
    0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
    0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
    0x11       GPL,SL  R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
    0x30       GPL,SL  R/O     16  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
    0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
    0xb7       GPL,SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
    0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
    0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer
    
    SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log (GP Log 0x03) not supported
    
    SMART Error Log not supported
    
    SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 0 (1 sectors)
    Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
    # 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      6305         -
    # 2  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6300         -
    # 3  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6158         -
    # 4  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6155         -
    # 5  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6154         -
    # 6  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6153         -
    # 7  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6153         -
    # 8  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6153         -
    # 9  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6153         -
    #10  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6153         -
    #11  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6153         -
    #12  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6153         -
    #13  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6153         -
    #14  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6153         -
    #15  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6153         -
    #16  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6153         -
    #17  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6132         -
    #18  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6132         -
    #19  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%      6132         -
    
    SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
     SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
        1        0        0  Not_testing
        2        0        0  Not_testing
        3        0        0  Not_testing
        4        0        0  Not_testing
        5        0        0  Not_testing
    Selective self-test flags (0x0):
      After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
    If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
    
    SCT Status Version:                  3
    SCT Version (vendor specific):       0 (0x0000)
    Device State:                        Active (0)
    Current Temperature:                    29 Celsius
    Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     16/51 Celsius
    Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     16/60 Celsius
    Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
    
    SCT Temperature History Version:     0 (Unknown, should be 2)
    Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
    Temperature Logging Interval:        10 minutes
    Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/ 0 Celsius
    Min/Max Temperature Limit:            0/ 0 Celsius
    Temperature History Size (Index):    0 (455)
    Temperature History is empty
    
    SCT Error Recovery Control command not supported
    
    Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
    Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
    0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 2) ==
    0x01  0x008  4            4199  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
    0x01  0x010  4            6316  ---  Power-on Hours
    0x01  0x018  6     75794083015  ---  Logical Sectors Written
    0x01  0x028  6     74298888900  ---  Logical Sectors Read
    0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
    0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
    0x04  0x010  4           17758  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
    0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
    0x05  0x008  1              29  ---  Current Temperature
    0x05  0x010  1              36  ---  Average Short Term Temperature
    0x05  0x018  1              35  ---  Average Long Term Temperature
    0x05  0x020  1              50  ---  Highest Temperature
    0x05  0x028  1              21  ---  Lowest Temperature
    0x05  0x030  1              43  ---  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
    0x05  0x038  1              31  ---  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
    0x05  0x040  1              35  ---  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
    0x05  0x048  1              35  ---  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
    0x05  0x050  4               0  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
    0x05  0x058  1              70  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
    0x05  0x060  4               0  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
    0x05  0x068  1               0  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
    0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
    0x06  0x008  4           17758  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
    0x06  0x010  4            6388  ---  Number of ASR Events
    0x06  0x018  4             774  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
    0x07  =====  =               =  ===  == Solid State Device Statistics (rev 1) ==
    0x07  0x008  1              20  ---  Percentage Used Endurance Indicator
                                    |||_ C monitored condition met
                                    ||__ D supports DSN
                                    |___ N normalized value
    
    Pending Defects log (GP Log 0x0c) not supported
    
    SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
    ID      Size     Value  Description
    0x0001  2            3  Command failed due to ICRC error
    0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
    0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
    0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
    0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
    0x0008  2            3  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
    0x0009  2          903  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
    0x000a  2          460  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
    0x000f  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
    0x0010  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, non-CRC
    0x0012  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
    0x0013  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, non-CRC
    0x0002  2            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
    0x0005  2            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
    0x000b  2            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
    0x000d  2            0  Non-CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
```

The 1tb drive(not faulty one):

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 3.5" DT01ACA... Desktop HDD
Device Model:     TOSHIBA DT01ACA100
Serial Number:    Y3N4LUAPS
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 ff7d02fa0
Firmware Version: MS2OA7L0
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Dec 04 08:15:22 2022 TST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Disabled
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]
Wt Cache Reorder: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                                        was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                ( 7264) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 121) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     PO-R--   100   100   016    -    1
  2 Throughput_Performance  P-S---   142   142   054    -    70
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS---   123   123   024    -    188 (Average 183)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--C-   099   099   000    -    4176
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   005    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         PO-R--   100   100   067    -    0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   P-S---   108   108   020    -    37
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--C-   099   099   000    -    10410
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--C-   100   100   060    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   099   099   000    -    4014
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   097   097   000    -    4178
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--C-   097   097   000    -    4178
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O----   136   136   000    -    44 (Min/Max 13/53)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O---K   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ---R--   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O-R--   200   200   000    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      1  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL     R/O      7  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x08       GPL     R/O      2  Power Conditions log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x20       GPL     R/O      1  Streaming performance log [OBS-8]
0x21       GPL     R/O      1  Write stream error log
0x22       GPL     R/O      1  Read stream error log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       256 (0x0100)
Device State:                        SMART Off-line Data Collection executing in background (4)
Current Temperature:                    44 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     40/44 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     13/53 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
Temperature Logging Interval:        1 minute
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/60 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:           -40/70 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (74)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
  75    2022-12-04 06:08    38  *******************
  76    2022-12-04 06:09    39  ********************
 ...    ..( 50 skipped).    ..  ********************
 127    2022-12-04 07:00    39  ********************
   0    2022-12-04 07:01    40  *********************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  *********************
   4    2022-12-04 07:05    40  *********************
   5    2022-12-04 07:06    39  ********************
   6    2022-12-04 07:07    40  *********************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  *********************
  10    2022-12-04 07:11    40  *********************
  11    2022-12-04 07:12    41  **********************
  12    2022-12-04 07:13    41  **********************
  13    2022-12-04 07:14     ?  -
  14    2022-12-04 07:15    40  *********************
  15    2022-12-04 07:16    41  **********************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  **********************
  18    2022-12-04 07:19    41  **********************
  19    2022-12-04 07:20    42  ***********************
 ...    ..(  8 skipped).    ..  ***********************
  28    2022-12-04 07:29    42  ***********************
  29    2022-12-04 07:30    43  ************************
 ...    ..( 14 skipped).    ..  ************************
  44    2022-12-04 07:45    43  ************************
  45    2022-12-04 07:46    44  *************************
  46    2022-12-04 07:47    43  ************************
  47    2022-12-04 07:48    43  ************************
  48    2022-12-04 07:49    44  *************************
 ...    ..( 25 skipped).    ..  *************************
  74    2022-12-04 08:15    44  *************************

SCT Error Recovery Control:
           Read: Disabled
          Write: Disabled

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4            4014  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4           10410  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6     38134590720  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6       776921956  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6     73456085565  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6       827436983  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x03  =====  =               =  ===  == Rotating Media Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x03  0x008  4           10320  ---  Spindle Motor Power-on Hours
0x03  0x010  4           10320  ---  Head Flying Hours
0x03  0x018  4            4178  ---  Head Load Events
0x03  0x020  4               0  ---  Number of Reallocated Logical Sectors
0x03  0x028  4             216  ---  Read Recovery Attempts
0x03  0x030  4              12  ---  Number of Mechanical Start Failures
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4               0  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              44  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x010  1              40  N--  Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x018  1              38  N--  Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              53  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1              13  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x030  1              48  N--  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x038  1              25  N--  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x040  1              46  N--  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x048  1              25  N--  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x050  4               0  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              60  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x05  0x060  4               0  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
0x05  0x068  1               0  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x06  0x008  4           21066  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
0x06  0x010  4           16960  ---  Number of ASR Events
0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

Pending Defects log (GP Log 0x0c) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  2            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  2            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0009  2            2  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  2            1  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  2            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000d  2            0  Non-CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
```

Comment: Check/show SMART please.

Comment: Are you certain DiskGenius is complaining about the SSD, not the other drive? Can we see SMART for other drive too?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Yes, I'm sure about that, I will post other smart later.(the format may not be same because I'm on windows now)

Comment: Why do you have such a high `Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct`? This could be the root cause of the damage.

Comment: @mashuptwice I don't know, either. The drive is from my small server, it only has 3 unexcepted power loss(the power cable screw up), and it was fully new bought from my friend 1 year ago (fully new because the package was not even opened).

Comment: You missed to deliver proof of whatever shows errors in a traceable way. There is one SMART line that caught my attention:
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   100   100   000    -    774

Answer (score 0):

You missed to deliver proof of whatever shows errors in a traceable way.
You did not explain why you think that your EFI partition is screwed.

There is one SMART line that caught my attention:

`199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   100   100   000    -    774`

Put your SSD in a different machine, see if the erroneous behaviour persists.
If you intend to run chkdsk, duplicate your SSD before if there is data without backup that you still wish to recover.